# load a url in new tab jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am trying to open a url in a new tab with the below code, but can't able to do so

```
partial_url = '/products/compare/?ids=f25353f4e8f2,598f4166e2d9,39c17d76-133e-4a86-bf39-d4d5e600349a&fis=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10'

final_url = window.location.host + partial_url + '&new_html=true';

var win = window.open(final_url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

The above code was opening a new tab but with `about:blank` in the address bar, but was not opening my url, so what's wrong in the above code ?

```
Note: 

final_url = 'http://localhost:8000/products/compare/?ids=f25353f4e8f2,598f4166e2d9,d4d5e600349a&fis=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10&new_html=true'
```

Comment: Can you console "final_url" and show output?

Comment: Looks weird, your same code is working fine for me. Have you type="text/javascript" attribute in your script tag? also try to define "var final_url" once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: by default window.open will open in a new tab

```
var win = window.open(final_url);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove window.location.host
try it

```
final_url = partial_url + '&new_html=true';
```